# The 'xref' keyword was not found or the xref table is malformed

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I have trouble find out what is wrong with my pdf file, form https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx I get `The 'xref' keyword was not found or the xref table is malformed. The file trailer dictionary is missing or invalid.` Base64 of my pdf:

```
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
```

PS.: https://www.base64decode.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `startxref` is wrong. It should be `450` to point to the `x` in `xref`, and not `430` that you have it as now.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it indirectly pointed the problem. Offset was right, but file was saved wrong,working with file as binary solve problem. Due to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c `Characters may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to the conventions for representing text in the OS`, hence binary was shifted by `\n` conversion.

Comment: *"it indirectly pointed the problem. Offset was right"* - Well, strictly speaking it *directly* pointed at the problem, the offset in the file *is* wrong. It might have been correct in some intermediary representation in memory and it might be the right offset if you save that representation differently, but as you only showed the file and not your code, the problem in the file as shared is in focus.

Comment: @mkl okey, agreed.